# Post request with GuzzleHttp

Tags: http, post, guzzle

I'm trying to make a post request like this example:

```
$response = $guzzle->post('http://www.website.com/abc.asp?2014:62/9/931/99999', [
                 'body' => [ 'f' => 'json' ]
            ]);
```

But when i run that code i get an 505 error because the url was literally encoded after `?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable query string encoding. Try this example:

```
$request = $guzzle->createRequest(
                  'POST', 
                  'http://www.website.com/abc.asp?2014:62/9/931/99999', [
                     'body' => [ 'f' => 'json' ]
               ]);

$request->getQuery()->setEncodingType(false); // magic line :-)

$response = $guzzle->send($request);
```